# How to allow everyone on SMB (Samba) to edit

Tags: networking, samba

So I set up a server on my home network using Samba, I use a Linux computer running Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. However I want to connect to the server on a MAC. I can find the file fine however when I drop a file in it says "The operation can’t be completed because you don’t have permission to access some of the items."

If anyone knows what to do or can refer me to a video please do so

Thanks

Comment: Try with manual [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Samba/SambaServerGuide).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your share writable, by default it is `read-only`

- On Ubuntu you need to right click on your share folder and in settings check what you want (writable).
- Or from command line `chmod +w yoursharedfolder`